# How to Design BMS in simulink?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, matlab, simulink, bms

I have designed a battery pack of li-ion batteries.

> At the initial stage I have given 0 at both constant blocks. This indicates there is no charging or discharging
> [image]

> In the second fig I have applied charging to the circuit and it will charge Li-ion batteries. It will increase its SOC from 20% to 100%
> [image]

> Now in the third case the charged li-ion batteries will discharge and their SOC will decrease

[image]

Now the Problem is SOC of all batteries is the same at the beginning which is 20%.If I changed SOC like 20%,35%,70% then It will give unpredictable output. How to add or build BMS in MatLab simulation software? Please help if you can

Comment: _"If I changed SOC like 20%,35%,70% then It will give unpredictable output." - what do you mean by 'unpredictable'?

Comment: Are the left set of batteries **permanently** connected in series? If so, I think, there is *no* way you can charge them all to the same state of charge since the series connection means that the same current passes through them. If the batteries have self leakage, then run the simulation without charging and discharging for a huge amount of time and allow the state of charge to equalise by leakage. *Then start charging*.